# Many-to-Many Association between view and table in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, orm

Within Entity Framework (DB First) I've been able to link a view to a table with a One-To-Many link by manually mapping an association to the key. I'm wondering if and how I could achieve the same conceptual linkage using Many-To-Many?

EF automatically converts the linking table between two tables into the appropriate Many-To-Many association using the foreign keys. Correct me if I'm wrong, but a foreign key cannot reference a view so I'm trying to recreate this automated procedure manually without the existence of foreign keys.

I managed to use a linking view containing the keys of both the view and table. Obviously the view lacks any FK constraints but it was possible to manually map a Many-To-Many association to it. Whilst the model saves and validates I'm met with an error at runtime: "The given key was not present in the dictionary".

Putting the reasons for this desire aside, is what I want to do possible? If I can do it with One-To-Many shouldn't Many-To-Many be possible too?